# alternative to container_of()

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I am a newbie trying to code a serial driver(PCI based ) and I don't want to use the `container_of()` for lack of downward compatibility.The kernel version I may compile the module
would  be < 2.6.x so I want to make it compatible with most of the old and new versions.

i want to access the structure member(s) of a serial card driver.the structure is a custom one containing the atomic variable for example - use_count and the related operation on it-- `atomic_inc(&serial_card->use_count)`.I dont want to access them by using the `container_of()` function which will give me the containing structure
Is there any alternate to container_of() function.If I am not wrong the text LINux device drivers by Allesandro Roubini describes a way on page no 174 | Chapter 6: Advanced Char Driver Operations.
But I am still fixed about how to assign something like `struct scull_dev *dev = &scull_s_device`.
if the structure itself contains a variable of type `struct pc_device *dev`,the above statement  populates a similar variable and that is assigned to dev,

in my case i have declared a structure and related function  as below

```
struct serial_card
{
  unsigned int      id;     // to identify the each card
  //atomic_t        use_count;      //  variable used to check whether the device is already opened or not  
  wait_queue_head_t rx_queue[64];   // queue in which the process are stored
  unsigned int      data_ready[64]; //  queue in which  the process is ready 
  unsigned int      rx_chan;    // used by interrupt handler 
  unsigned int      base, len; // holds physical base address , holds the total area ( for each card )
  unsigned int      *base;      // holds virtual address 
  /*struct cdev     cdev;           //  kernel uses this structure to represent the EACH char device 
 not using the new method to represent char devices in kernel instead using the old method of register_chrdev();*/

  struct pci_dev        *device;    // pci_dev structure for EACH device.
  //struct semaphore    sem;        //Semaphore needed to handle the co-ordination of processes,use incase need arises
};

static struct serial_card *serial_cards;    // pointer to array of structures [ depending on number of cards ],NO_OF_CARDS #defined in header file


static int serialcard_open(struct inode *inode,struct file *filep)
{

  //getting the structure details of type struct serialcard,using the pointer inode->i_cdev and field type cdev

  //struct serial_card *serial_cards = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct serial_card, cdev);

  // read the current value of use_count

  static int Device_Open = 0;
  if ( Device_Open )            //Device_Open is static varibale used here for checking the no of times a device is opened
  {
    printk("cPCIserial: Open attempt rejected\n");
    return -EBUSY;
  }
  Device_Open++;


  // using the card so increment use_count
  //atomic_inc(&serial_cards->use_count);
  //filep->private_data = serial_cards;

  return 0;
}
```

the complete description on page 174 - 175  is as follows

> #### Single-Open Devices
>
> The brute-force way to provide access control is to permit a device to be opened by
>   only one process at a time (single openness). This technique is best avoided because it
>   inhibits user ingenuity. A user might want to run different processes on the same
>   device, one reading status information while the other is writing data. In some cases,
>   users can get a lot done by running a few simple programs through a shell script, as
>   long as they can access the device concurrently. In other words, implementing a singleopen
>   behavior amounts to creating policy, which may get in the way of what your
>   users want to do.  Allowing only a single process to open a device has undesirable properties, but it is also the easiest access control to implement for a device driver, so it’s shown here.
>   The source code is extracted from a device called scullsingle.

The scullsingle device maintains an atomic_t variable called scull_s_available; that
variable is initialized to a value of one, indicating that the device is indeed available.
The open call decrements and tests scull_s_available and refuses access if somebody
else already has the device open:

```
static atomic_t scull_s_available = ATOMIC_INIT(1);
static int scull_s_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
  struct scull_dev *dev = &scull_s_device; /* device information */
  if (! atomic_dec_and_test (&scull_s_available)) {
    atomic_inc(&scull_s_available);
    return -EBUSY; /* already open */
  }

  /* then, everything else is copied from the bare scull device */
  if ( (filp->f_flags & O_ACCMODE) = = O_WRONLY) {
    scull_trim(dev);
    filp->private_data = dev;
    return 0; /* success */
  }
```

The release call, on the other hand, marks the device as no longer busy:

```
static int scull_s_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
  atomic_inc(&scull_s_available); /* release the device */
  return 0;
}
```

Normally, we recommend that you put the open flag scull_s_available within the
`device structure (Scull_Dev here)` because, conceptually, it belongs to the device. The
scull driver, however, uses standalone variables to hold the flag so it can use the same
device structure and methods as the bare scull device and minimize code duplication.

Please let me know any alternative for this

thanks and regards

Answer (score 4):

perhaps I am missing the point, but "cotainer_of" is not a function, but a macro. If you have porting concerns, you can safely define it by yourserlf if the system headers don't implement it. Here a basic implementation:

```
#ifndef container_of
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
 ((type *)                              \
   (  ((char *)(ptr))                   \
    - ((char *)(&((type*)0)->member)) ))

#endif
```

Or here's the implementation - more accurate - from recent linux headers:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
                const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); 
                (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Comment: Hi Giuseppe ,thanks for the reply,but the main point you are missing is : I am not using cdev structure in my struct serial_card,so I cannot use the macro container_of(),but I need to know the cdev structure information through any other alternate means so that i can use it like atomic_inc(&serial_cards->use_count); ..this statement can only be possible if I have the struct serial_card information.the way to obtain that information is container_of(),which I cannot use since I am not using explicit cdev structure,I am using register_chrdev() way which will create a default cdev structure .Thx

Comment: As far as I know, the "old way" was based on the intensive use of minor numbers, used as indices of an array of preallocated structures. Instead of extracting your structure from i_cdev, you extract the minor and then take the correct item from the array... oh, it was so much time ago... ;-)

Comment: Hi again! Did you solve your problem? I am interested in this issue too. Thank you!

Comment: Hello Giuseppe Guerrini,thanks for understanding this complex issue.You have asked me to extract using the minor and take the correct item from array ...but HOW ??? .Please elaborate ...I am a newbie..sorry for replying late ,my work had kept me busy.Also can u please help me to understand how I can keep a count of how many times a device is opened ..suppose there are 12 device with minor numbers ..if 1 device is opened for the second time I should not allow that to happen,,i tried using an array for struct,having 2 fields,1 for count and other for minor number any code ..will be of great help

Comment: manually keeping a count of open device.this is what I want to achieve,also the new version of kernel and Roubini's 3rd edition text shows a way but thats only if you are using an Explicit cdev structure.I am not using a cdev structure in driver ..I am going by the old way i.e register_chrdev() which internally allocates the structure.On page 58 Roubini says "Be sure to use iminor to obtain the minor number from the inode structure, and make sure that it corresponds to a device that your driver is actually prepared to handle." but how ?? please let me know ..thanks for your interest again

Comment: int minor = iminor( inode ) or even iminor( fikp->f_dentry->d_inode) ....this way i can get the minor number but ,i get stuck here ...how exactly to proceed with getting the rest...spending sleepless nights behind these challenges ..its interesting though

Comment: Basically, the minor number represents the particular instance of your device. "Old style" drivers mantained an array of "possibly supported devices" and used the minor as index in it.It's a very rude way, but it works if you can accept to limit the number of supported devices (i.e. the number of nodev in /dev with the same major and different minor numbers).

Comment: E.g. do ls -l /dev/tty[0-9], you will see that each different ttyN terminal takes a different minor number, so the driver could have an array of "struct ttystate", one for each tty number (the real driver uses probably a smarter way). In your case, one of the field of the struct may be a counter of "open". I hope that this can halp you. Bye!

Comment: hi Giuseppe Guerrini  a field in the struct might contain a counter...if you have a piece of code for both container_of() alternative and even the manual open count method please do let me know ...I can't still figure out,I have just started to learn LDD.thanks well in advance

Comment: I suggest you to study the Linux' "generic parallel driver" (online here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/lp.c). In particular, the function lp_open shows how to protect the function with a critical section (mutex) and how to use "minor" to get the instance variables (lp_table[minor]). I think that this is a quite simple example, so you can use it as a starting point. Bye!

Comment: hello Giuseppe Guerrini thanks for the link,but please dont forget to update me about the method to access struct cdev using alternate method (not using container_of()) macro..will surely follow and do as you have said .incase if i get more doubts will let you know ..hope you dont mind helping me a newbie....thanks again

Answer (score 2):

In that code the containerof is used to store and retrieve the correct dev structure easily. The correct structure can be retrieved inside the read and write functions also without accessing to the private_data.
I do not know why you do not want to use private->data and containerof, but you can always retrieve your minor number from the struct file pointer.

```
int minor=MINOR(filp->f_dentry_d_inode->i__rdev);
```

then accessing to your multiple devices vector using something like

```
struct scull_dev* dev = &scull_devices[minor]:
```

and using it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use filp->privatedata to store "per-open" information that you also use in read/write.  You will need to decide what to store to ensure that the right information is available.

Probably you want two structures.  One "device structure" and one "open structure".  The open structure can get dynamically allocated in "open" and stored at private_data.  In release, it gets freed.  It should have the members such that you can use them in read/write to get access to the data you need.

The device structure is going to be per "card".  In your driver init, you probably want to loop on the number of cards and create a new device structure (serial_card) for each.  You can make them a static array, or dynamically allocate, it doesn't matter.  I would store the minor number in the structure as well.  The minor number is chosen by you, so start with 1 and go through #cards.  You can reserve "0" for a system level interface, if you want, or just start at 0 for the cards.

In open, you will get the minor number that the user opened.  Go through your serial_card list looking for a match.  If you don't find it, error out of open.  Otherwise, you have your info and can use it to allocate a "open structure", populate it, and store it in filp->private_data.

Answer (score 0):

@Giuseppe Guerrini Some compiler just cannot recognize the linux implementation of container_of.
The basic define is fine, but I wonder if there is any safety or compatibility risk at this implementation:

```
 #ifndef container_of
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
 ((type *)                              \
   (  ((char *)(ptr))                   \
    - ((char *)(&((type*)0)->member)) ))

#endif
```